# Unserialize Array in cookie PHP

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, serialization

I'm currently creating a cookie with a name and a value (serialized array of objects):

```
include_once './Model/Winkelwagenitem.php';

$winkelwagenProduct = array (
        //aantal + ID
        new WinkelwagenItem(1,257),
        new WinkelwagenItem(3,258),
        new WinkelwagenItem(1,259)
);    

$cookie_name = "winkelwagen";
$cookie_value = serialize($winkelwagenProduct);;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value); 

//echo "Data to be stored (serialized): ".$cookie_value."<br>";

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])){
        echo "Cookie not being set";
} else {
        echo "cookie created";
}
```

All going well. Now in another php file I Access this cookie and i need to unserialize it and return the objects that are in the cookie:

```
 if(isset($_COOKIE["winkelwagen"])){
    echo "Deze cookie (".$_COOKIE["winkelwagen"].") bestaat";
    foreach ($_COOKIE["winkelwagen"] ....){
        .....
        unserialize(....)
        ....
    }
} else {
    echo "deze cookie bestaat niet";
}
```

I have not really an idea of what has to come in the foreach-loop?

Help please?

Comment: `$_COOKIE["winkelwagen"]` only contains one value, why do you need a loop, why not just `unserialize( $_COOKIE["winkelwagen"] )`?

Comment: More objects to be added

Comment: How do you add more objects to the same key in a cookie? If you mean add more to the serialized array, that doesn't matter, you would to iterate over those after it's unserialized

Comment: Like @adeneo said, if your value not one value. Try to check it first, you need a function to check your data type first. Check my answer, may be you get a point of that function. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function to Unserialize array, here is the function :

```
function _unserialize($data)
{
    $data = @unserialize(strip_slashes($data));

    if (is_array($data))
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $val)
        {
            if (is_string($val))
            {
                $data[$key] = str_replace('{{slash}}', '\\', $val);
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }

    return (is_string($data)) ? str_replace('{{slash}}', '\\', $data) : $data;
}
```

Maybe this'll help you...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over that cookie variable. What you store in the cookie is just a value because you are serializing.

So when you want to use those objects, you need to unserialize and use.

Your code should look like this:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["winkelwagen"])){
    //! You have your array of object here, use it as required
    $winkelwagenProduct = unserialize($_COOKIE["winkelwagen"]);
} else {
    echo "deze cookie bestaat niet";
}
```

Few tips:

- You need to include the class definition of `WinkelwagenItem` on the page where you are unserializing it
- Cookie has limited size, don't store something which is going to be huge.
- All cookies are sent on every HTTP request by the client. That means, the heavier is the cookie data, the heavier will be the each HTTP request. So don't store unnecessary things in cookies.